# In python, headings not in the same row

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, header

I extracted three columns from a larger data frame (recent_grads) as follows...

```
df = recent_grads.groupby('Major_category')['Men', 'Women'].sum()
```

However, when I print df, it comes up as follows...

```
                                         Men    Women
Major_category      
Agriculture & Natural Resources      40357.0    35263.0
Arts                                134390.0    222740.0
Biology & Life Science              184919.0    268943.0
Business                            667852.0    634524.0
Communications & Journalism         131921.0    260680.0
Computers & Mathematics             208725.0    90283.0
Education                           103526.0    455603.0
Engineering                         408307.0    129276.0
Health                               75517.0    387713.0
Humanities & Liberal Arts           272846.0    440622.0
Industrial Arts & Consumer Services 103781.0    126011.0
Interdisciplinary                     2817.0    9479.0
Law & Public Policy                  91129.0    87978.0
Physical Sciences                    95390.0    90089.0
Psychology & Social Work             98115.0    382892.0
Social Science                       256834.0   273132.0
```

How do I get Major_category heading in the same row as Men and Women headings? I tried to put the three columns in a new data frame as follows...

```
df1 = df[['Major_category', 'Men', 'Women']].copy()
```

This gives me an error (Major_category not in index)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi man you should try reset_index https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html:

```
df = df.groupby('Major_category')['Men', 'Women'].sum()
# Print the output.
md = df.reset_index()
print(md)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you want to convert the groupby object back to a dataframe try:

```
df['Major_category'].apply(pd.DataFrame)
```

Comment: I tried it and then I had done the print(df) and then got the key error: 'Major_category'

Comment: Okay, try `df.to_frame(name = "Major_category").reset_index()`

Comment: I gave me the following error when I tried to print df                            
AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'to_frame'

Answer (score 0):

For those who still look for the solution:

df.reset_index(inplace=True)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).